# DataGridView - Text from webpage

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGridView on my C# Windows Forms Application. I need to get each cell to contain the contents of a webpage that I'm in the process of creating. For example:

Record1, Cell1 = Line1 of webpage.
Record1, Cell2 = Line2 of webpage.

Record2, Cell1 = Line3 of webpage.
Record2, Cell2 = Line4 of webpage.

I need to be able to do that consistently possibly in a while loop. But how would I do this? Also, I need the code to enter text into a dataGridView cell.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code. Did these lines come from an already created page or you just have an input mechanism for setting the cells?

Comment: The point is, I have no idea where to start and was wondering if I could recieve a link to how I would read a website line by line entering text into each dataGridView cell.

Comment: perhaps you are looking for screen scraping?

Comment: Any ideas where to start on that?

Comment: if you are not in fight with google then google should give you this https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=screen+scraping+c%23&aq=f&oq=scree&aqs=chrome.1.57j59j0j5j60l2.2454&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this algorithm.

1. Code a webpage crawler/**scraper**(gets data from a webpage).
2. Save contents of webpage in an XML.
3. Read the XML accordingly and display the data in the cells you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've assume that you already have a `DataGridView` control on your form and you have our lines in a collection of lines (i.e. `List<string>`).

This would be a head start:

```
for (int index = 0; index < lines.Length; )
{
  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(lines[index], ++index < lines.Length ? line[index] : "");
}
```

you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) as a reference.